My program is not updating after I save the file
My program was working while it was an untitled file. I saved it as a .C file and then the output stopped changing. I messed around with the program and re-ran it but the output remained the same. If I save and close the file, the output updates to the last saved program but then it's the same problem all over again. If I select all the code and run it the output is correct, but it's annoying to do.
Program at time of saving:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   printf("hello world");
}

Output:
[Running] cd "e:\C_files\" && gcc Engine_Balencing.c -o Engine_Balencing && "e:\C_files\"Engine_Balencing
hello world
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.181 seconds

Altered program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    printf("hello world__3");
}

Output:
[Running] cd "e:\C_files\" && gcc Engine_Balencing.c -o Engine_Balencing && "e:\C_files\"Engine_Balencing
hello world
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.181 seconds

[Running] cd "e:\C_files\" && gcc Engine_Balencing.c -o Engine_Balencing && "e:\C_files\"Engine_Balencing
hello world
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.192 seconds


Welcome to SO. Did you save the file? Did you edit the correct file?

yes. I double checked

Add something like #error fail to your code, and build it. If it compiles cleanly without an error, you're not building the code you think you are. Maybe you have different copies in different folders.

I would suggest check for if you have done the installation process on the windows correctly or not,because I was facing the same problem as you are currently facing then i just did some research and checked my installed packages of mingw and it worked
